# screen : automatic creating or reattaching sessions in different configurations

Tags: terminal, configuration, gnu-screen, workspaces

What's clean way to achieve, following functionality:

```
function screen_create_or_reuse(){
if [ running_screen_session "$1" ]; then
    reattach_screen_session screen_name_"$1"
else
    create_screen_session "$1" screen_config_"$1" screen_name_"$1"
fi
}
```

Currently, I have to worry if session is already runnning (`screen -ls` or `screen -wipe`). Depending on it, if it's not running: create session with custom configuration and name manually (`screen -c config -S name`) and than reattach manually. I'd like one command `screen_create_or_reuse name` which handles all those details.

I thought about creating bash script which detects presense of session etc., but I see screen has already a lot of options, maybe I would do overkill.

What's clean way of achieving above, with screen ?

Answer (score 2):

The following option is from `man screen`:

```
   -d -R   Reattach a session and if necessary detach or even create it first.
```

Use it with `-S` to set the session name.

Comment: is it realiable to use it with `-c` as well ? (`-c` for configuration)

Comment: Do I really have to use it with `-S` for name ? As I run `screen -dr NAME -c conf` it works ? So what's clean and reliable way ?

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, `-S foo -d -RR` will do what you want: it attaches to the session whose name you specify, and creates one if one doesn't exist already.

I like to go a bit further, and look for name-specific configuration files.
This lets me define different environment variables, startup applications, and so on for different session names.

This is my file `etc/screen/0.screenrc`, which is sourced by other session-specific configuration files:

```
source ~/.screenrc
unsetenv DISPLAY
msgminwait 0
msgwait 0
screen -t post_initialization 39 sh -c 'sleep 1; screen -X msgwait 5; screen -X msgminwait 1'
```

This is a sample per-session configuration file `etc/term/emacs.screenrc`, which starts one window running Emacs (no longer useful with Emacs 23 which can attach to multiple terminals).

```
sessionname emacs
source 0.screenrc
screen -t emacs emacs -nw
```

And this is an adapted version the script I use to invoke these sessions. Call it with e.g. `scr emacs` to pick up the session shown above. If there is no configuration file corresponding to the session name in `~/etc/screen`, I run a shell.

```
#!/bin/sh
session_name=$1; shift
if [ -r "$HOME/etc/screen/$session_name.screenrc" ]; then
  exec screen -S "$session_name" -d -RR -c "$HOME/etc/screen/$session_name.screenrc" "$@"
else
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then set "$SHELL"; fi
  exec screen -S "$session_name" -d -RR -c "$HOME/etc/screen/0.screenrc" "$@"
fi
```

Comment: Looks very useful . Especially `source` command. As I stated, I'd like to ensure there is one session for each name. IMHO `-d -R` will be better in my case, cause I will be warned in case if there will be more than one session with given name. What do you think about it?

Comment: Are `screen -dR name -c conf` and `screen -S name -d -R -c conf` equivalent?